# r manipulation a character vector for a sequence

Tags: r, string

I have a list of question ids as below:

```
ids <- c("1_a","1_b","1_c","2_a","2_b","2_c","3_a","3_b","3_c")
```

`1_,2_,3_` at the beginning of the ids represent grouping (factor) so there are three factors for a total of 9 questions. Considering this grouping factor variable, I would like to generate a character variable as below.

```
#for the first factor
(1_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
(1_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
(1_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
(1_b, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
(1_c, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
(1_c, fixed[3]) = 0.0;

#for the second factor
(2_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(2_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
(2_b, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(2_b, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
(2_c, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(2_c, fixed[3]) = 0.0;

#for the third factor
(3_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(3_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
(3_b, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(3_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
(3_c, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
(3_c, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
```

The logic behind the desired output is similar to factor analysis. When it is the first question, the same question coefficient is fixed for other factors. For example, for questions 1_a, I need to have two lines that are fixed for the second and third factors so that the coefficient will be freely estimated for the first factor.

For the first factor, the coefficients in the`[]` should be `2` and `3`.
For the second factor, the coefficients in the`[]` should be `1` and `3`. and
For the third factor, the coefficients in the`[]` should be `1` and `2`

Did anyone have anything similar before?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `fixed` in the example

Comment: It is not clear about `fixed`.  Perhaps `i1 <- 1:3; lapply(i1, function(x) c(outer(sub("_[A-Z]+", "", grep(x, ids, value = TRUE)), fixed[i1[-x]], FUN = function(u, v) sprintf('(%s, %s) = 0.0;', u, v))))`

Comment: Hi amisos, I've read your question a couple of times and I can't figure out your logic. Can you edit your question to show clearly how each element of each string becomes the expected output?

Comment: If you meant the `fixed` as the middle value 'AB', 'CD', etc. `lapply(i1, function(x) {i2 <- grep(x, ids); v1 <- sub('_[A-Z]+', '', ids[i2]); fixed <- unique(sub('^\\d+_([A-Z]+)_.*', "\\1", ids[-i2])); c(outer(v1, fixed, FUN = function(u, v) sprintf('(%s, %s) = 0.0;', u, v)) )})`

Comment: "fixed" is just a word, it could be any other word. it is not a function or anything.

Comment: @amisos55 in the string `"1_AB_a"`,  I was thiinking that it is `"AB"` that you considered as fixed

Comment: Snap! sorry, I forgot to remove that! now edited.

Comment: @amisos55 Can you please check if this works `i1 <- 1:3; lapply(i1, function(x) c(outer(grep(x, ids, value = TRUE), setdiff(i1, x), FUN = function(u, v) sprintf('(%s, fixed[%d]) = 0.0;', u, v))))`

Comment: your suggestion produced the results correctly in a list of three. Is there a way to combine them into one character list?

Comment: @amisos55 please check my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want to create a single `vector` based on the unique numeric part in 'ids', loop over the unique integers ('un1') with `lapply`, extract the elements that partially matches the 'ids' with `grep`, do an `outer` paste with `format` with the rest of the unique values (`setdiff`), and `unlist` the `list` to create a single `vector`

```
un1 <- as.integer(unique(sub("_\\D+", "", ids)))
v1 <- unlist(lapply(un1, function(x) c(outer(grep(x, ids, value = TRUE), 
     setdiff(un1, x), FUN = function(u, v)
        sprintf('(%s, fixed[%d]) = 0.0;', u, v)))))
cat(paste(v1, collapse="\n"), "\n")
#(1_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
#(1_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
#(1_c, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
#(1_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(1_b, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(1_c, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(2_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
#(3_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;
```

Comment: what if the ids are random numbers? Would this work? let's say`ids <- c("54_a","54_b","54_c","44_a","44_a","44_a","32_a","32_a","32_a")` I would still give the factor numbers as `1,2,3` in the `[]`s.

Comment: @amisos55 In that case, instead of looping over 'un1', I would do lapply(seq_along(un1)` and inside the `grep` .e. `grep(un1[x], ids, value = TRUE)` and `setdiff(un1, un1[x])`

Comment: Did you mean like this:  `ids <- c("54_a","54_b","54_c","44_a","44_b","44_c","32_a","32_b","32_c")
un1 <- as.integer(unique(sub("_\\D+", "", ids)))
v1 <- unlist(lapply(seq_along(un1), function(x) c(outer(grep(un1[x], ids, value = TRUE), 
                                                        setdiff(un1, un1[x]), FUN = function(u, v)
                                               sprintf('(%s, fixed[%d]) = 0.0;', u, v)))))
cat(paste(v1, collapse="\n"), "\n")`

Comment: @amisos55 yes, it gives me `unlist(lapply(seq_along(un1), function(x)  c(outer(grep(un1[x], ids, value = TRUE), setdiff(un1, un1[x]), FUN = function(u, v) sprintf('(%s, fixed[%d]) = 0.0;', u, v)))))#
 [1] "(54_a, fixed[44]) = 0.0;" "(54_b, fixed[44]) = 0.0;" "(54_c, fixed[44]) = 0.0;" "(54_a, fixed[32]) = 0.0;"
 [5] "(54_b, fixed[32]) = 0.0;" "(54_c, fixed[32]) = 0.0;" "(44_a, fixed[54]) = 0.0;" "(44_b, fixed[54]) = 0.0;"
 [9] "(44_c, fixed[54]) = 0.0;" "(44_a, fixed[32]) = 0.0;" "(44_b, fixed[32]) = 0.0;" "(44_c, fixed[32]) = 0.0;"
[13] "(32_a, fixed[54]) = 0.0;"..`

Comment: ok. what I meant was even though the items ids are random, I would keep the order of the factors numbers as `1,2,3`. not `54,44,32` in the `[]`.  The output should be `"(54_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;" `... sorry this is because the lack of clear description.

Comment: @amisos55 okay, in that case, just replace the `setdiff` part i..e `setdiff(seq_along(un1), x)`

Comment: @amisos55 i.e. `unlist(lapply(seq_along(un1), function(x)  c(outer(grep(un1[x], ids, value = TRUE), setdiff(seq_along(un1), x), FUN = function(u, v) sprintf('(%s, fixed[%d]) = 0.0;', u, v)))))#
 [1] "(54_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0;" "(54_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0;" "(54_c, fixed[2]) = 0.0;" "(54_a, fixed[3]) = 0.0;"
 [5] "(54_b, fixed[3]) = 0.0;" "(54_c, fixed[3]) = 0.0;"...`