# Manipulating a character vector by considering a grouping sequnce in r

Tags: r, arrays, character

I had a similar question before [here][1] but this one is slightly different.

I have and id vector `ids`, a grouping variable `group`, and a factor variable `factor` which has the initial numbers before `_` in `ids` variable.

```
ids <- c("54_a","54_b","44_a","44_c")
 group <- c(1,2)
  factor <- c(54,44)
```

The rules for the output:

1. the row that has `fixed[0]` should always equal to 1.
2. When it is the first factor, the row that has `fixed[1]` should equal to 1.
   , the row that has `fixed[2]` should equal to 0.
3. When it is the second factor, the row that has `fixed[1]` should equal to 0.
   , the row that has `fixed[2]` should equal to 1.
4. So the number in the `fixed[#]` represents the factor number and when that factor is considered, this row should be equal to 1.
5. The procedure needs to be replicated for the two groups (G1, G2)

my desired output is below:

```
#for the first factor first group
(G1, 54_a, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G1, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
(G1, 54_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 2

(G1, 54_b, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G1, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
(G1, 54_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 2


#for the second factor
(G1, 44_a, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G1, 44_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 1
(G1, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2

(G1, 44_c, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G1, 44_c, fixed[1]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 1
(G1, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2


#for the first factor second group
(G2, 54_a, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G2, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
(G2, 54_a, fixed[2]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 2

(G2, 54_b, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G2, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
(G2, 54_b, fixed[2]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 2


#for the second factor
(G2, 44_a, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G2, 44_a, fixed[1]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 1
(G2, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2

(G2, 44_c, fixed[0]) = 1.0; # this is always 1
(G2, 44_c, fixed[1]) = 0.0; # 0 for factor 1
(G2, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2
```

I was able to produce the first row for each chunk of output

```
Fixed.Set.1 <- c()
for(g in 1:length(group)) {
  

  fixed.set.1 <- paste0(paste("(", "G",g,", ",ids, ","," fixed[0]) = 1",collapse="; ", sep=""),"; ")
  Fixed.Set.1 <- c(Fixed.Set.1, fixed.set.1)
}

> Fixed.Set.1
[1] "(G1, 54_a, fixed[0]) = 1; (G1, 54_b, fixed[0]) = 1; (G1, 44_a, fixed[0]) = 1; (G1, 44_c, fixed[0]) = 1; "
[2] "(G2, 54_a, fixed[0]) = 1; (G2, 54_b, fixed[0]) = 1; (G2, 44_a, fixed[0]) = 1; (G2, 44_c, fixed[0]) = 1; "
```

Any ideas on how to deal with the rest?
Thanks
[1]: [r manipulation a character vector for a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62960955/r-manipulation-a-character-vector-for-a-sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First atempt:

```
library(stringr)

# define df for all ids and group combinations
group_g <- paste("G", 1:length(group), sep ="")
df <- data.frame(ids, group = rep(group_g, each = length(ids)))

# empty vector
vec <- NULL


for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  
  res <- which(str_extract(df[i, "ids"], "[0-9]{2,}") == factor)
  
  text <- paste("(", df[i, "group"], ", ", df[i, "ids"], ", fixed[", c(0:length(factor)) ,"]) = ", ifelse(res == 0:length(factor) | 0 == 0:length(factor), "1.0", "0.0"),";", sep = "")
  
  vec <- c(vec, text)
}

vec
```

Comment: thanks for your response. the rows that have `fixed[0]` should be equal to 1 always. Is there a way to quickly adjust that in your code? See the first rule in my post please.

Comment: I added a second condition in the ifelse-function. Now it might work.