# manipulation vectors with a sequencing logic in r

Tags: r, character, sequence

I have and id vector `ids`, a grouping variable `group`, and a factor variable `factor` which has the initial numbers before `_` in the `ids` variable.

```
ids <- c("54_a","54_b","44_a","44_c")
 group <- c(1,2)
  factor <- c(54,44)
```

so, `54_a` and `54_b` belong to the first factor `54`. `44_a` and `44_b` belong to the second factor `44`.

The rules to write out the output is:

1. When the `id` belongs to the first factor `fixed[#]` should be
   `fixed[1]`.
2. When the `id` belongs to the second factor `fixed[#]`
   should be `fixed[2]`.
3. The procedure repeats for group 1 and 2 (G1, G2).

> ```
> (G1, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
> (G1, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
> (G1, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2
> (G1, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2
> ```

> ```
> (G2, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
> (G2, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 1
> (G2, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2
> (G2, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0; # 1 for factor 2
> ```

Any thoughts?
Thanks!

This is a slightly simpler version of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63697028/manipulating-a-character-vector-by-considering-a-grouping-sequnce-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `outer` :

```
c(t(outer(paste0('G', group), ids, function(x, y) {
  ind <- match(sub('_.*', '', y), factor)
  sprintf('(%s, %s, fixed[%s]) = 1.0', x, y, ind)
})))

#[1] "(G1, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0" "(G1, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0"
#[3] "(G1, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0" "(G1, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0"
#[5] "(G2, 54_a, fixed[1]) = 1.0" "(G2, 54_b, fixed[1]) = 1.0"
#[7] "(G2, 44_a, fixed[2]) = 1.0" "(G2, 44_c, fixed[2]) = 1.0"
```

We pass `id`'s and groups in the function and `match` the part of `id`'s to get `fixed#`.